# Marker click event in android map using osm

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap

i am using following code for creating marker(bitmap),how to add click event for marker. i use graphhopper android for OSM map

`startMarker = createMarker(startPoint, R.drawable.marker_departure); layers.add(startMarker);`

add use createMarker method

`public Marker createMarker(LatLong p, int resource) {
        Drawable drawable = activity.getResources().getDrawable(resource);
        Bitmap bitmap = AndroidGraphicFactory.convertToBitmap(drawable);
        return new Marker(p, bitmap, 0, -bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
    }`

and how to add text near to marker

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use following code its works for me

```
MyMarker frommarker = newMyMarker(activity,newLatLong(fl.latitude,fl.longitude), AndroidGraphicFactory.convertToBitmap(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_departure)), 0, 0);
mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(frommarker);
```

and mymarker class

```html
public class MyMarker extends Marker {
        private Context ctx;
 
        
        public MyMarker(Context ctx, LatLong latLong, Bitmap bitmap, int horizontalOffset,
                        int verticalOffset) {

            super(latLong, bitmap, horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onTap(LatLong tapLatLong, Point layerXY, Point tapXY) {
            if (this.contains(layerXY, tapXY)) {
}
}
```

Comment: how you are getting mapView object?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this, may be this will help full.

```
layers.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                       //Your stuff

                });
```